default behavior of boost::beast::http::async_read
I'm running boost 1_74 and have found some behavior that is not described in the docs. With a call like:
http::async_read(*socket, data, request, read_handler);

where request is a boost::beast::http::request<boost::beast::http::string_body>, I've noted that the target string will always be empty when a malformed HTTP request is read.
Can this behavior be relied upon in the read_handler?

No. It's not required for the documentation to specify every behavioral detail.
In fact, libraries like Asio and the standard library actively strive to minimize the interface contract, because over-specified contract hurt implementation evolution. In normal English: it allows them to improve implementations without breaking users.

A corollary to this is Hyrum's Law

So, no you should not rely on this behavior. It's easy not to, because you have the error code from the parser. If you feel it's somehow a big boon to usability, or to prevent certain types of bugs (e.g. security bugs), you might raise a feature request asking whether it is worth pinning down this behavior in specification.
TL/DR
No, but you're doing everything right by even noticing this is a relevant question!
In the light of Hyrum's Law, always have tests in case you depended on implicit behavior. It will also help you see when the specifications change (breaking change), which is a whole lot more reliable than hoping the release notes are clear, complete, and actually used :)
PS
I suspect that any parse failure in the headers will leave the body in the state it was in. That's still unspecified and coincidental.
I suspect that when a parse error occurs e.g. during chunked encoding the body state will be inconsistent/partial (also depending on the implementation of BodyReader). Again, that's just a reasonable expectation, not guarantees. It makes sense to realize this because the BodyReader can potentially even have external side-effects.
